# Regarding a SEO Search and html characters

Tags: php, utf-8, uri, slug

I am developing a site which allows user to search through the site database, The search script is customized and its a simple case of using "match" against in SQL.

the workflow is as :

User enters the text ( which can be text+number+some special symbols).
form is submitted to a page which will generate a SEO URL ( [http://www.example.com/search/URLENCODE(SEARCHTERM)](http://www.example.com/search/URLENCODE%28SEARCHTERM%29)).

Now the problem I have is that some characters are being shown in slug, some arent. What am I doing wrong?

Code :

In Search Redirector Page :

```
$title=rawurldecode($_GET['searchtext']);
$title=ucfirst(mb_strtolower($title,'UTF-8'));
$title=preg_replace('/[^-\pL.\s0-9- ?\'"+:()<>&]/u', '', $title); //replaces everything else apart from characters and symbols mentioned above.
$title=htmlspecialchars(trim(html_entity_decode($title)));
$slug=rawurlencode($title);
$link="http://www.example.com/search/".$slug;
```

and in Search Page its as :

```
$title=rawurldecode($_GET['searchtext']);
$title=preg_replace('/[^-\pL.\s0-9- ?\'"+:()<>&;]/u', '', $title);
$title=str_replace("%09","",$title);
$title=str_replace("%20"," ",$title);
$title=str_replace("-"," ",$title);
$title=trim($title,' ');
$title=trim($title,'%20');
$title=trim($title,'-');
$title=trim($title,' ');
$title=html_entity_decode($title);
```

and then SELECT id,Title from table match(title) against ('$title');

The above works fine for :

- UTF Strings.
- Strings with Characters only.
- Strings like "Title ;)" and "Title :-)"

The problem is , it doesnt work with some characters which have "&" in converted form like <,>,& sign etc.

What is making it wrong?
Please guide.

Comment: There are characters in a URL that have specific meanings. You might want to modify those to be interpreted by your encode so that they don't muck up your URL when you get it back.

Comment: @Fluffeh, can u please tell what am I doing wrong...or atleast what can I do to make this stuff work as I want.Basically, All i want is user enter a word( with characters) and some allowed Symbols.

The search should be safe, no xss/sql injection ( though I am using HTML Purifier+Prepared Statements).

And lastly after security I want the URL slug to be safe for SEO.

Comment: @CyberWizard: It starts with understanding "your" problem. You're especially looking for *reserved characters* in an URI. Understand how it works, then decide what you want to make use of it. And don't get fooled by marketing: Any properly written URI is *safe* for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

> What is making it wrong?

Your expectation.

> Please guide.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986 - a good entry in your case is probably [2.2. Reserved Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).

Comment: +1 - what I said with a link and a specific pointer to the bit of the (really fricken) long specification that solves the problem.